# MySQL JSON Storage vs Two Tables

Tags: php, mysql, json

Would there be any benefit in using JSON to store data in a table vs having a separate meta table?

Here is the original schema:

```
Users Table      UserId  |  Username  |  Etc...
                 5       |  John      |

Avatar Table     Id      |  UserId    |  ImageName         |  ImageType
                 1       |  5         |  example.png       |  original
                 2       |  5         |  example_thumb.png |  thumbnail
```

Here is the JSON version:

```
Users Table      UserId  |  Username  |  Avatar
                 5       |  John      |  {"original":"example.png","thumbnail":"example_thumb.png"}
```

I personally like the json version and would prefer to use it, but how much slower is it than the original version?

In my case, I need the user's avatars (and different sizes) almost every query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a big text file to store serialized *(no matter what kind of serialization)* means :

- No need to modify the schema to add / remove columns
- Ability to store pretty much anything you want
- BUT : you will not be able to work with those data on the MySQL side -- especially, you won't be able to use those in a `where` clause.
  Basically, this means using MySQL to store data -- and nothing more than storage

If you only want to use those data on the PHP side, and never have to work with the on the SQL side, I suppose that storing everything a big text field is a solution.

*(and, in this case, I don't see why it would be slower than another solution)*

Comment: The where clause was becoming the issue. On most pages I need all sizes. So I thought that if I were already getting all the sizes for each page, I might as well make the sql a little cleaner

Answer (score 2):

> ... but how much slower is it than the
>   original version?

No way to answer this but to test and benchmark it.

I am wary of using MySQL to store serialized data for the reasons PM mentions on his answer. I personally would just change the users' table's schema to:

```
Users    UserID  | UserName  |  Avatar  |  Avatar_Thumb
```

If you really need to get the thumbnail that often. There isn't much value in using another table here, and the serialized version will consume 30 extra bytes *per row* for no good reason.

Comment: if i used a varchar for the json column, would it still use that much more. Or is a text column the only way to go?

Comment: @mtokoy I mean, because you are now storing `{"original":"example.png","thumbnail":"example_thumb.png"}` instead of just `example.png` and `example_thumb.png` you are wasting space.

Answer (score 2):

I see no use in such fields at all.

There is a rule of the thumb: **if you see no use for the relationships, you don't need entire data structure then**

There is no sense in giving those pictures names other than user's id
Being named as `566.png` and `566_thumb.png` these avatars will require no records in the table at all

Comment: what about for caching reasons? keeping the same name after an image change would be a bad idea. Also, what if the image is a jpeg? How would I know?

Comment: @mtokoly there is no reason to keep images in different formats. But if you insists, it's not a problem too - just give them pictures all the same extension, no matter of the actual format. And there are not a single problem with caching.

Comment: so, would you convert every image to a png (or jpg) and keeping the same name doesnt cause problems with browser caching?

Comment: @mtokoly not with displaying (browsers do get actual image type from the file heading, they do not tryst content-type HTTP headers) nor with caching. A good web-server always keep an eye on the file's modification time. you can easily try it and see though

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use something like mongoDB and store directly JSON alike objects. Fast and reliable. No idea if you had a particular need for mysql.