# Storing playlist tracks as JSON string or mySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, soundcloud

I want to store a playlist of tracks from SoundCloud in a mySQL table.

I was wondering if i could have one table with the:

- playlist id
- playlist name
- array of tracks

The array being a JSON string containing all the tracks ID's and their play order.

This would save space over the mySQL table method where i would not store an array in the playlist table but create another table for tracks that stores:

- track id
- playlist id
- track order value

Is the JSON string storage a good idea or not?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL JSON Storage vs Two Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283757/mysql-json-storage-vs-two-tables) - there are similar questions as well. You need direction if you want to store data *serialized* or in it's *normalized form*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you are concerned about performance? From the sounds of it, you only need a few tables and probably are not storing thousands of rows. MySQL will perform perfectly well under such minimal usage. Personally, I say model your data accurately for the RDBMS and only worry about performance when you actually start to have performance problems. By modeling you data accurately, you solve the problems others have talked about with searching for tracks. It also makes it easy see what playlists a specific track is in. I'd have this for tables:

Playlist

- Playlist ID
- Playlist Name

Track

- Track ID
- Track Name

PlaylistTracks

- Playlist ID
- Track ID
- Track Order

Trying to prevent performance issues before you have performance issues is almost always a bad idea. Who is to say encoding/decoding the JSON representation is not going to be slower than MySQL? Why give up the enhanced functionality of modeling the data accurately if the potential performance concern is not actually there?

Comment: Ok this makes sense to me, I just wondered if it was a good idea or not. and its not, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The immediate flaw I see with storing the track info in single json field is that you will not be able to easily search. You will need to use the 'LIKE' operation on a large field that most likely will not have a good index.. alphanumeric indexes have a length limit on them. I think it is 255 chars, but you might need to verify it. This also means however many chars you use as the index will have to be unique, but with json, you will eat up a lot of space with the encoding overhead right at the beginning of your string.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not plan to search inside your playlists, I guess it is not so bad.
NoSQL rocks :)